# Did my EFI and Boot partitons get switched on upgrade to 18.04?

Tags: boot, grub2, partitioning, upgrade, uefi

Ok, so this is a weird one. After I upgraded to 18.04 I was constantly running out of space on /boot... I couldn't have more than two kernels installed at a time and I needed to autoremove/autoclean before every kernel upgrade.

So I did some digging and found that my EFI partition was 500Mb and my boot partition only 250Mb. This makes NO sense... of course when my system was originally set up (when I installed 16.04) these values were reversed. I mean they had to have been as I could have like 4 kernels at a time on my old install. I solved the problem by resizing the drives [as outlined in my blog post here](http://piratesinteepees.org/boot-partition-in-ubuntu-keeps-running-out-of-space-after-upgrade-to-18-04/), but I am wondering:

Did the upgrade to 18.04 swap my EFI and Boot partitions for some reason? Is this possible? Is this happening to anyone else???

Now that I have fixed it, my relevant df looks like this:

```
/dev/sda2                    667M  333M  300M  53% /boot
/dev/sda1                    104M  8.4M   95M   9% /boot/efi
```

On my original install I did not do "something else" and let Ubuntu install do its thang. There is no reason to create a 500mb efi partition and I am assuming the auto partition install would not do so.

If my EFI drive was originally sda2 (is this even possible?) maybe the upgrade wanted to put EFI on starting partition?

I am curious to hear any and all thoughts/opinions on what is going here. At first I thought I was going crazy, but then I remembered that I went there a long time ago... please comment on this matter! Thanks!

Comment: An upgrade will not change the EFI System Partition.

Comment: @mook765 Thank you! I would think the same thing! On my original install I did not do "something else" and let Ubuntu install do its thang. There is no reason to create a 500mb efi partition.... how could this even happen?

Comment: I think that just some defaults have been used when the partitions were created automatically during your first install.

Comment: then why could I install like 4 kernels at a time when I was on 16.04? this is so weird.... I really appreciate your interest in this thanks

Comment: `do-release-upgrade` will not change any partitions. If you installed fresh (18.04 over 16.04)  the ESP should remain unchanged in size, a fresh install will use an existing ESP.

Comment: that is what I would think! I just can't figure out how I ended up with a gigantic efi drive and a minuscule boot drive... I have been using this computer for over 3 years and haven't noticed this issue until I upgraded to 18.04

Comment: Best not to have a separate /boot partition. Then space is used in /boot folder in much larger / (root). But if using full drive encryption, you will normally have a /boot partition. Some server installs may need /boot also.

Comment: I am using lvm so separate boot partition is required... this was all set up automatically when I did my initial install